# InputStream throwing SocketTimeOutException on read when file is not available

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, socketexception

Trying to read some image files from a server and using socket programming for the same.

But I am getting socketTimeOut exception when there is no file exist. Not only that loosing the connection to the server.

How can I avoid loosing the connection to the server when there is no file exist.

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(socket().getInputStream());

int i = -1;
while ((i = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {
byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
}
```

In the above code I am getting exception, when I call read() on bufferedInputStream. How can I handle this exception and loosing connection to server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't get that  exception 'when the file [doesn't] exist'. You get it when you have set a read timeout and no data has arrived within the timeout, if your timeout is too short, raise it. If you want to wait forever, remove it. It's your timeout, you set it.

If you get a SocketTimeoutException you don't lose the connection. What makes you think you did?

Comment: This post helpmed me where and why I am getting exception. Thanks.

Comment: As you said if the connection is not closing or disposing after the exception, we should handle the cleaning of streams. If we are not closing the stream, then there would be a stream which is binded to the socket. If we close the socket does it internally closes the associated streams with that socket. My java skills are very very poor. Please correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: @Upendra What are you talking about? I said *nothing* about 'handling the cleaning of streams'. Don't close anything, just note the timeout, maybe count it, and try again. When you get too many timeouts, or read() returns -1, or you get a different IOException, close the socket, or better still the output stream if any you have wrapped around it. Closing the socket closes its streams and vice versa.